# How to use a drop down menu to insert into a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a single column table with relevant entries in it... and within my APEX 18.1 installation I have a page that has a drop down which works. There's a list of databases to select in a table called "LINK_NAME". So the item type is a select list, and the related query is "select link_name from link_name;"

The problem is, that this is merely a select list. Which is fine... but I want the value you select to insert into the column "LINK_NAME" in another table when you click "NEXT" on the page.

Is it possible for someone to point me in the right direction as to how I can get the contents of the drop down to insert onto the related table in the intended way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select List's LoV query requires two values to be selected so - maybe a typo, maybe not, but it should be something like

```
select link_name   display_value,
       link_name   return_value
from link_name
```

`NEXT` button should perform the following:

- submit page
- (you should) create a process which is ran when that button is pressed; it will

  ```
  insert into another_table (link_name) values (:P1_LINK_NAME);
  ```

  (presuming item's name is `P1_LINK_NAME`).
- create a branch which will navigate to the "next page" once the `NEXT` button is pressed

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, but following your syntax results in an ORA error as follows:  ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 3, column 1: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined</p>

Comment: You're welcome. What exactly returns that error? If you're not sure, enable debug mode, run the page and then view debug results. Because, in code I wrote there's nothing *ambiguous* (at least, I think so).

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, with your help I finally figured out what I wanted to do. 

The select list is based on:

select link_name a,   
       link_name b  
from link_name;

And I created a PL/SQL INSERT "After Submit" process that corresponded to 

the items in the content body with code as follows:

insert into link2 (link_name,email_address)values(:P7_PICK_TARGET,:P7_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

:P7_PICK_TARGET is the drop down value and the email address is entered manually.

Job done.

Comment: Nice; I'm glad you made it work! Thank you for the feedback.